# Rails restrict user login session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) for Rails to prevent multiple user sessions at same time using `:session_limitable`.

But now I need to change the scenario to

> allow user to have 2 sessions at same time,

so that the same website can be opened on both desktop and mobile device.

Does anyone know if this can be done using this gem only? or should I change the approach?

Comment: I think using simple devise without any extension would do your job

Comment: @chaitanya can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to do it on your own.
See [session_limitable](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/master/lib/devise_security_extension/hooks/session_limitable.rb) as a starting point.

Basically you'll need to store existing session ids in DB (with timestamp?) and check current session id on authorization